# How to remove action part in zend framework URLs

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

I`m using zend framework and my urls are like this :

```
http://target.net/reward/index/year/2012/month/11
```

the url shows that I'm in reward controller and in index action.The rest is my parameters.The problem is that I'm using index action in whole program and I want to remove that part from URL to make it sth like this :

```
http://target.net/reward/year/2012/month/11
```

But the year part is mistaken with action part.Is there any way ?!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's the link to the [router docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html), but I have very little idea on how to configure routes in the manner you are requesting. It is possible shouldn't be to difficult

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html). With routes, you can redirect any URL-format to the controller/action you specify. For example, in a `.ini` config file, this will do what you want:

```
routes.myroute.route = "reward/year/:myyear/month/:mymonth"
routes.myroute.defaults.controller = reward
routes.myroute.defaults.action = index
routes.myroute.defaults.myyear = 2012
routes.myroute.defaults.mymonth = 11
routes.myroute.reqs.myyear = "\d+"
routes.myroute.reqs.mymonth = "\d+"
```

First you define the format the URL should match. Words starting with a colon `:` are variables. After that you define the defaults and any requirements on the parameters.

Comment: You have to set custom routes for all pages you want to remove 'index'

Comment: @tasmaniski, exactly. The router tries to match the current URL with any of the routes you have defined. If no match is found, the 'normal' way of routing the URL will be used.

Comment: @Abadis Confirm the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use controller_plugin to control url .
as you want create a plugin file (/library/plugins/controllers/myplugin.php).
then with preDispatch() method you can get requested url elements and then customize that for your controllers .
**myplugin.php**

```
class plugins_controllers_pages extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $int = 0;
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();  
        if($params['action'] != 'index' ) AND !$int)
        {
             $int++;
             $request->setControllerName($params['controller']);
             $request->setActionName('index');
             $request->setParams(array('parameter' => $params['action']));
             $this->postDispatch($request);
        }
    }
}
```